# Creating a fast and simple image search with Google Images (iframe)

Tags: image, iframe

I am doing a university project involving a sort of social network for recipes.

In order to have the database populated by ingredients, I have written a simple form that may add them to the db. Ingredients contain an image which I'd like people to add.

In order not to have my website flooded with uploads, I was thinking about a small google images iframe in which people click on the image they want, so that I can display it by its link (I expect every ingredient to be within the very first results in google images).

My problem is that Google's toolbar (the one they introduced with Google+) is quite annoying, and it takes a lot of the space I want the iframe to occupy.

Are there any workarounds? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's kind of a "Forever alone" question (I have even got the Tumbleweed achievement on this one :V ).

I arranged something myself, so I'll share :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>



$.getJSON("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=tex&callback=?",
          {
            unescapedUrl: "any"
          },
          function(data) {
            $.each(data.responseData.results, function(i,results){
                  $("<img/>").attr("src", results.unescapedUrl).attr("id", "img"+i).appendTo("#images");
                  $("#img"+i).wrap($("<a/>").attr("href", results.unescapedUrl));
              if ( i == 1 ) $("#images").append("<br />");
            });
            return false;
          });


</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="images">

</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tex thanks for your code its the only one i can find online that works for this but was wondering what is the variable which controls the number of images brought in and I noticed they are not the top image results so wondering what defines the image that it choses.

Comment: this api is no longer available